# How to send emails to newsletter subscribers using mail chimp in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailchimp

I am using the below code to send email to newsletter subscribers in website, but this code does not seems to  work, can anyone guide me, how to integrate mail chimp in asp.net website: -

```
 listSubscribe cmd = new listSubscribe();

        listSubscribeParms newlistSubscribeParms = new listSubscribeParms
        {
            apikey = apikey,
            id = "1",
            email_address = "test@gmail.com",
            merge_vars = new Dictionary<string, object>(),
            double_optin = false,
            email_type = EnumValues.emailType.html,
            replace_interests = true,
            send_welcome = false,
            update_existing = true
        };

        listSubscribeInput newlistSubscribeInput = new listSubscribeInput(newlistSubscribeParms);

        var subscribeSuccess = cmd.Execute(newlistSubscribeInput);
```

Comment: There's code missing.  For one thing we don't know what type of object cmd is.  Also, what, exactly isn't working?  Are you getting an error message, or are mails just not showing up?

Comment: no I am not getting any error message , emails are not showing up. I am using Mail chimp api "PerceptiveMCAPI.dll" and "CookComputing.XmlRpcV2.dll" for this